# Import Cython header from another package

Tags: python, cython, python-import

I have a package called `A`:

```
A/
  __init__.py
  _test.pyx
```

I have the source for another package called `B`:

```
B/
  __init__.py
  _wrapper.pxd
  _other.pxd
  _other.pyx
```

`_wrapper.pxd` wraps a C library. I'd like to `cimport` `_wrapper.pxd` in `A/_test.pyx`

So I do this in `_test.pyx`:

```
from B cimport _wrapper
```

my `setup.py` looks like this:

```
ext_modules = cythonize([
           Extension("A._test", ["src/A/_test.pyx"], include_dirs=["/path/to/B", "."])])
```

When I compile I get `B.pxd not found` followed by a bunch of errors.

How can I import a cython module from another package into my package?

Answer (score 10):

#### Short answer

In order to cimport .pxd files from other packages you need to give your package a __init__.**pxd** file. Then you can treat your package B as a cython package and do not need to worry about include paths.

#### Reproduction

I tried to reproduce the error like this:

```
setup.py
  A/
    __init__.py
    _test.pyx
  B/
    __init__.py
    _wrapper.pxd
    _other.pxd
    _other.pyx
```

_wrapper.pxd

```
cdef inline foo():
    print("42")
```

_test.pyx

```
from B cimport _wrapper

cpdef bar():
    _wrapper.foo()
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = cythonize([
        Extension("A._test", ["A/_test.pyx"])])
setup(ext_modules=ext_modules)
```

And it did not work with this error:

```
A/_test.pyx: cannot find cimported module 'B'
Compiling A/_test.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing A/_test.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from B cimport _wrapper
^
------------------------------------------------------------

A/_test.pyx:1:0: 'B.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
[...]
```

This should be what you faced.

#### How to solve this

For me, adding an empty __init__.pxd file solved the problem. I did not need to specify an include path or have a __init__.py and used the files as listed above. All files which are not shown above I kept empty.

```
$ touch B/__init__.pxd

setup.py
  A/
    __init__.py
    _test.pyx
  B/
    __init__.pxd
    _wrapper.pxd
    _other.pxd
    _other.pyx

$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
$ ipython

In [1]: from A import _test

In [2]: _test.bar()
42
```

I hope this works for you.

#### Alternative

If it is an option, consider moving the _wrapper.pxd to the A folder.
Then you can directly use:

```
cimport _wrapper
```

I guess you would like to preserve the package structure as you have laid it out, so this is just here for completeness sake.